# DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder optionsBuilder.isConfigured is always false

Tags: dbcontext, ef-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I am using two db context one for Identity and one for ef core. The ApplicationDbContext intity framework works. The SKGDMD_WebSiteContext is created by EF core power tools. It says to do what I have tried to be secure. But when I run it, I get an error

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.)

Program CS

```
\`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext\<ApplicationDbContext\>(options =\>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDbContext\<SKGDMD_WebSiteContext\>(options =\>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity\<ApplicationUser\>(options =\> options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles\<IdentityRole\>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores\<ApplicationDbContext\>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();'
```

Context I am having the problem with

```
public partial class SKGDMD_WebSiteContext : DbContext
{
public SKGDMD_WebSiteContext()
{
}

    public SKGDMD_WebSiteContext(DbContextOptions<SKGDMD_WebSiteContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OnModelCreatingGeneratedProcedures(modelBuilder);
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

}
```

In the program CS I also tried to change SKGDMD_WebSiteContext with DbContext and this resulted in the same error. What am I doing wrong? If I do the OnConfiguring override it works. It tells me not to use that for production code so I would like to set this up the way it is supposed to. The SQL config works since it works when I log in and do Identity related tasks. I want to have all the connection strings in the json file and have them be injected through the program.cs if at all possible.

Comment: Looks like you have a code which uses this constructor `public SKGDMD_WebSiteContext()` rather than the one configured from DI.

Comment: @IvanStoev How would I fix this? I am new to the DI world. The SKGDMD_WebSiteContext() is used for all my stored procedures.